# Android loading circle

Tags: android, progress-bar

I need to show standard loading circle on half-opaque background **above** current layout (with background and buttons etc). I found ProgressBar and how it works, but I need to render it on existing layout, and that's the problem.
 To be more clear - imagine login screen with some image and button aka "Register". On click I need to show partly visible black background and a loading circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and see if this works (use it as an inner class)

```
 private class executeHospitalNameGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {  
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(SettingsActivity.this); 

        private Context mContext;

        public executeHospitalNameGet(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {  
            Dialog.setMessage("Getting Hospitals...");  

            Dialog.setTitle("Requesting Hospital Name");
            Dialog.show();  
        }  

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {  
        //DO WORK HERE
            return null;
        }  

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {  
                Dialog.dismiss();
        }  

    }
```

You would call it with this

```
new executeHospitalNameGet(getApplicationContext()).execute();
```

Comment: is there a way to set *show time*? I mean it disappears very quickly. UPD: never mind, works great

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RelativeLayout`, It will allow you to have overlapping `View`s, check out this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like modal dialog with loading animation...

check it out this... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog